# AdminModel object has no attribute 'obj'

Tags: python, django

I have model with manytomany field, and in admin panel in my AdminModel class I use this code:

```
def get_object(self, request, object_id, to_field):
    # Hook obj for use in formfield_for_manytomany
    self.obj = super(GoalAdmin, self).get_object(request, object_id)
    return self.obj

def formfield_for_manytomany(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
    if db_field.name == "reviewers":
        kwargs["queryset"] = Goal.objects.get(id=self.obj.id).reviewers.all()
    return super(GoalAdmin, self).formfield_for_manytomany(db_field, request, **kwargs)
```

It works fine, until I try add goal from admin panel. Than I get this error:

```
'GoalAdmin' object has no attribute 'obj'
```

How can I fix it?

UPD: errors happens here:

```
 kwargs["queryset"] = Goal.objects.get(id=self.obj.id).reviewers.all() 
Variable    Value
self       <goals.admin.GoalAdmin object at 0xa7d472cc>
db_field    <django.db.models.fields.related.ManyToManyField: reviewers>
request     <WSGIRequest: GET '/goals/goal/add/'>
kwargs      {}
```

Comment: Please show the full traceback. Where is this error happening?

Comment: Is the happening when you are trying to save for first time ?

Comment: Updated. No, hapenning when I click add button, and after that I get this error. Even form not shows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your error is presumably happening because `get_object` has not been called at the point where `formfield_for_manytomany` runs.

There may be ways of fixing that, but this is really the wrong approach. This sort of thing should be done by defining a custom form and using that in the admin class.

```
class GoalAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(GoalAdminForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if self.instance is not None:
            self.fields["reviewers"].queryset = Goal.objects.get(id=self.instance.id).reviewers.all()

class GoalAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = GoalAdminForm
```

Comment: Uh, thank you so much for your propose to use custom form. Now it works like needed. 1 point added to knowledge base about right approaches.